# Get all points of a parabola

Tags: mathematics

I'm wondering how to get all points (x,y) that constitute a given parabola.
It's barely to simulate a jump of an object from point A to point B.
I know:
-The coordinate of point A
-The coordinate of point B
-The coordinate of the parabola's top

What i'm trying to do is to loop from *start_x* to *dest_x* to calculate the Y-coordinate at that moment, but I don't know how to do that part.

```
pixels = []
for x in start_x to dest_x
   y = (calculate the Y-coord here based on x )
   pixels.push( [x,y] )
end
return pixels
```

My math skills are not exceptional.
Thank you.

Comment: you'll need a third point to specify the parabola, or the direction of the "gravity" and its strength.

Comment: You're using too much data. If you know the parabola's top coordinate then you'll need one more point only and everything is done, but you have a second point too and this can lead you to undesired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there is no parabola that goes through three given points. However, if you loosen the problem constraints and only define the Y coordinate of the parabola’s top and allow its X coordinate to be free, there is usually a solution.

Given \$A_x\$, \$A_y\$, \$B_x\$, \$B_y\$ (A and B’s coordinates) and \$C_y\$ (the parabola’s top), one can find a parabola formula of the form:

$$f(x) = C_y - u (x - v)^2$$

One needs to find \$u\$ and \$v\$ in this formula. The constraints give us, after some maths:

$$
\begin{align}
    k &= \sqrt{\frac{C_y - A_y} {C_y - B_y}} \\
    v &= \frac{k B_x - A_x}{k + 1} \\
    u &= \frac{C_y - A_y}  {(A.x - v)^2}
\end{align}
$$

For instance if \$A = (0, 0)\$, \$B = (10, 5)\$ and \$C_y = 15\$:

$$
\begin{align}
    k &= \sqrt{\frac{15 - 0} {15 - 5}} &= 1.2247448714 \\
    v &= \frac{(1.2247448714 \times 10 - 0)} {1.2247448714 + 1} &= 5.505102572 \\
    u &= \frac{15 - 0}{(0 - 5.505102572)^2} &= 0.494948974
\end{align}
$$
Hence the formula:

$$
f(x) = 30 - 0.494948974 \times (x - 5.505102572)^2
$$

You can see this parabola going from \$(0,0)\$ to \$(10,5)\$ with a peak at \$Y = 15\$, as expected:

[image: plot of the example parabloa]

The following code should work:

```
pixels = []
k = sqrt((top_y - start_y) / (top_y - dest_y))
v = (k * dest_x - start_x) / (k + 1)
u = (top_y - start_y) / ((start_x - v) * (start_x - v))
for x in start_x to dest_x
   y = top_y - u * (x - v) * (x - v)
   pixels.push( [x,y] )
end
return pixels
```

Comment: Many thanks sam hocevar ! I'll let you know if it's applicable.

Comment: Unfortunately, i get some weird results. When the top_y is same as start_y, the movement becomes straight. It's normal. But when top_y is different, the movement become weirds. I don't know how to explain that. But after some investigations, il appears that the y at the beginning of the move is too inappropriate. It starts at 5838, for example. 
Whereas my start_y = ~200 and same for dest_y.

Comment: Please be more specific. Give the values for Ax, Ay, Bx, By, C.y, and what you get for k, u and v. Otherwise it’ll be difficult to tell what’s wrong.

Comment: Ha sorry. Ax = 120; Ay = 258; Bx = 378; By = 264; Cy = 228; k = 0.92582009...; u = -85.852319..; v = 119,408867....

Comment: Ah, but then Cy is smaller than Ay and By, so it’s no longer a “jump” above an object. If your Y axis goes downwards, you’ll need to use `k = -sqrt(…)` instead of `k = sqrt(…)`. Also, check your code, because with the formulas above you should get `k=0.912870929175277`.

Comment: Ah...It's because the origine of my landmark is the top-left of the screen. (image here)[link](http://i.imgur.com/nPvPdeY.png). Do I need to use a virtual landmark ? I tried -sqrt(..), but the movement is still weird.

Comment: Double check your code. sqrt() should return 0.912870929175277, not 0.92582009…

Comment: Ah. In fact I added +1 to the denominator when I tested a same value for top_y and dest_y (which lead to a division by zero error). I removed the +1. **Now with -sqrt, the movement is simply straight, no matter what value takes top_y.**

Comment: Any clues on what's wrong ? Do you have another solution ?. I tried to use a virtual landmark (the same as yours, origin at bottom-left) but it's still not good. Perhaps i'm missing something. What tool are you using to draw the above graph ? It's better if I get that tool to try and work better on the formula you gave to me. Anyway thank you a lot. Even if it doesn't work I learnt something.

Comment: In all honesty I think there’s a mistake somewhere in your code, because I’m pretty sure about the maths. To render the graphs I used Gnuplot with the following commands: http://paste.debian.net/317369/

Comment: FINALY !!!!!! The problem was the first code you gave me. I replaced k with k = -sqrt(1.0*(top_y-start_y)/(top_y-dest_y)) and v with v = (k*dest_x-start_x)/(k-1), like in the link above on debian. And it works ! Now I know how to make a realistic jump in my game. Thanks !

Comment: Now i'm curious of where comes that formula and what is exactly u and v and where have you learned such knowledges ?